# AddThis LIKE/+1 .live('click'.. jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, click, google-plus-one, addthis

I am trying to call a function after clicking facebook like button which I added to my website using AddThis. The problem is, that function didn't call if it is a like button. With share button everything works perfectly. Here is the code:

```
<body>
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like share_button" id="1"></a>    
</div>
</body>

$(function(){
    $('.share_button').live('click', function () {
    alert("hello");
    });     
});
```

Comment: Is the like button included via an iframe?

Comment: No. I copied example from the AddThis website

Comment: I tried to use onClick="function" as well. But got the same result. I wonder, why if i use share button - everything works fine, as for like buttons - they don't work!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use edge.create fir the like button. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Well, I use 2 other social networks as well. And i would like to create a unique script for 3 of them. And I'd prefer to use javascript/jQuery + AddThis, don't want to use APIs features.

Comment: AddThis uses the Facebook Like plugin. And this is the way to register the like event with it. What's the problem to call a generic function on edge.create?

Comment: I this case. 2 other buttons (G+ and Twitter) still won't work. That's why i said that I need a unique script for 3 social networks!